# Putting the backend and frontend services behind the same webserver in development

Tags: angularjs, django, configuration, webserver

We're developing a web application. The backend is implemented with Django and the frontend with AngularJS. The frontend is developed with standard frontend tools.

When deployed to a production machine, both frontend and backend will be served from the same domain (we'll use nginx as the webserver). On development, however, they are on different domains - lite-server serves the frontend files from localhost:3000 and the Django development server handles requests to localhost:8000 .

How can I put both on the same domain without installing nginx or another full-fledged server? We don't want to install and configure nginx on our development machine for every project we use, or every branch of every project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a project with the same stack. In my case, the entire frontend resides in a folder called *static* in the Django project directory. This static folder is defined as a static root in your Django project's **settings.py** file.

So, what happens is that the first html file, say **index.html** is served via Django using its rendering engine and after that all the partials are loaded using angular's `uiRouter` and ALL these partials reside in the static folder so that they can be served as static files.

Along with the partials, all other static media like CSS, JS and images also reside in the static root.

Snapshot of **index.html**:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="{% static 'development/assets/stylesheets/lib/normalize.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
</html>
```

As you can see, the paths for all static media are defined relative to thet static root. Here's how the static root definition looks like:

**settings.py**:

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Look here for `static` resource
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Here's a snapshot of `uiRouter`'s states defined in the angular application's config:

```
 $stateProvider.state("home", {
    url: "",
    controller: "HomeCtrl",
    templateUrl: "/static/development/templates/home.html"
 })
```